# Scraping links in Pattern library for Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, screen-scraping

I found code similar to this in a course I was taking. This code gets all of the links of a certain format that are mentioned in the source code of the webpage. I understand everything, except for the last line. The last line says the following:

```
 print link.attrs.get('href', '')
```

This works, however I'm unsure as to how the instructor figured out how to do this. I've looked through the documentation and I can't figure out what .get does. Could someone please let me know how I can find this information.

**Documentation for Pattern Library:** http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web

```
xml = requests.get("https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/2010_elections_governor_map.html").text
pattern = 'http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/????/governor/??/*-*.html'

dom = web.Element(xml)
all_links = dom.by_tag('a')

for link in all_links:
    print link.attrs.get('href', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would get all the href "hyperlinks" in that page. You can BeautifulSoup package which is more convinient

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = requests.get("https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/2010_elections_governor_map.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml") # lxml is just the parser for reading the html
soup.find_all('a href') # this is the line that does what you want
```

Comment: What's the difference between the pattern library  and beautiful soup?